# Implement "oAuth" user login system in android

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0

This is my second question regarding the **oAuth**. I have to implement login system using  the "oAuth". so I read lot of articles,but I can't get proper idea about these **oAuth flow** .If anyone can help me it'll be very helpful.I have a login API and I'm implementing these login system into the android application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Firebase` which is very easy to use and it will allow you to integrate facebook, twitter, google and email/password sign in and sign up in a easy way

Thanks

Comment: yeh i read that Firebase articles.i have a website.so i want create mobile app to that my website.so i create user details API.can i connect custon Api with Fierbase?

Comment: Yes you can Provide login with firebase and other information will remain on your website.

Comment: ok thanks for your support. actually  why we use the fierbase?

Comment: Firebase will provide easy way to integrate oauth with different providers.

Answer (score 0):

Google has some detailed sample on this topic you can check them out [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin)